# Hive Date Function: Fetching Month Part

Tags: hive

I have one date column in hive table in '03-06-2019' format.
  I want to fetch month as '06'and using below query

```
    select month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dat_col, 'dd-MM-yyyy')))) from table_name;
```

but its give output as 6.
  can anyone guide me how can i get 06 as output

Answer (score 0):

Use date_format function:

```sql
SELECT date_format(dat_col, 'MM') FROM table_name;
```

All date functions are available at this site: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions